# Is there a workaround to post inline JS code at any time?

Tags: 8, javascript

In Drupal 7 this worked:

```
drupal_add_js("jQuery(document).ready(function () { console.log('Hello!'); });", 'inline');
```

which aims to print the messages from the PHP code onto DevTools JS console in realtime (on each page request), however in Drupal 8 the above function has been [removed in favor of `#attached`](https://www.drupal.org/node/2169605).

I'm aware that I should use [`#attached` in my library](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/160270/1908), but sometimes the `$form` is not accessible and I'd like to invoke some JS code on certain functions and conditions (e.g. in `hook_tokens`) for debugging purposes (like injecting some PHP variables into the JS message during the processing).

Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: AFAIK this is a long and ongoing thread on drupal.org. https://www.drupal.org/node/2391025

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes the `$form` is not accessible and  I'd like to invoke some JS code on certain functions and conditions for debugging purposes.

Not sure if this will do for you, but posting this anyways just in case.

I use [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox and [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) for Chrome which allows your browser to load any js file that you write locally on this app/your computer.

Comment: It's handy, but I mean to print the messages from the server side, so I can also inject some backend variables from PHP and print them onto _DevTools_ console.